# Updating tsconfig.json target target to "es2022" causes "Property 'xx' is used before its initialization.ts(2729)"

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a lot of Angular code where I assign a property at its definition like the following...

```
 public errors$ = this.store$.select(fromApp.getErrors);

 constructor(private store$: Store<MyState>
```

As we can see `store$` is injected via the constructor. But now after changing `tsconfig.json target target to "es2022"` I get the error

```
Property 'store$' is used before its initialization.ts(2729)
```

Are we still able to assign such properties at the declaration?

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't know for sure if `store$` will be filled before or after `errors$`.
A good rule of thumb is to initialize simple properties within the declaration, but whenever it depends on something else, do it in the constructor.

```
public errors$: Observable<Foo>;

constructor(private store$: Store<MyState>) {
   this.errors$ = this.store$.select(fromApp.getErrors);
}
```

here, you're certain `store$` is filled before `errors$`.

Comment: Ok I use to always do that, but saw a lot of others always assigning at the declaration. I suppose I ca go back to the other way