# Angular 16 dependency injection issues when setting TypeScript target to ES2022

Tags: angular, typescript

I am in the process of upgrading my Ionic/Angular project to Angular 16, and latest TypeScript

I have

```
 "@angular/*": "^16.1.1"
 "typescript": "^5.1.3",
 "@ngrx/*": "^16.0.1"
```

When I run I get the message

```
[ng]     TypeScript compiler options "target" and "useDefineForClassFields" are set to "ES2022" and "false" respectively by the Angular CLI. To control ECMA version and features use the Browerslist configuration. For more information, see https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-browser-compatibility
[ng]     NOTE: You can set the "target" to "ES2022" in the project's tsconfig to remove this warning.
[ng] ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
```

and all runs fine.

So, if I take the advice of the above and set TS "target" to "ES2022, ie tsocnfig.jons now has

```
 "module": "es2020",    
 "target": "es2022",     
 "moduleResolution": "node",
 ....
```

it builds fine with no errors, but I jut get a white window.

Loooking in the console, I see

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe')
at app.effects.ts:28:66
at createEffect (ngrx-effects.mjs:86:49)
at new CurrentShiftEffects (current-shift.effects.ts:28:45)
at Object.CurrentShiftEffects_Factory [as factory] (ɵfac.js:1:1)
at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:9290:35)
at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9178:33)
at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:651:33)
at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:655:60)
at inject (core.mjs:738:12)
at ngrx-effects.mjs:523:17
```

Here is the code in question (which has been like this for years)

```
@Injectable()
 export class AppEffects {  

  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private dataService: DataService, private storage: LocalStorageService) { }
  
  public hydrateState$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(   // <---- ERROR here. this.actions$ is null!
    ofType(AppActions.hydrateState),
    mergeMap(() =>
      ...
  ));
```

If I put a breakpoint in the devtools debugger, I first see the constructor called, dnd note the actions$ is defined here...

[image]

Now continuing with F8, we get to the next breakpoint, and now everything in `this` is undefined (and hence the null error when we try to access `pipe` on `this.actions$`

[image]

Now if I enable the `pause on exceptions`

[image]

I see same thing all over the place, so it is completely broken.

I also had another dependency related issue as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76529602/updating-tsconfig-json-target-target-to-es2022-causes-property-xx-is-used-b), but this one I could fix just by move the assignment into the contructor.

But all these others I have no idea why these would occur. And it is all caused by setting, TS "target": "es2022". If I set this back to es2020, all is fine again.

Why is this recommended target causing this issue?

Comment: for ES2022 don't use the constructor for injection use the inject function. e.g. `private actions$ = inject(Actions)`

Comment: But we can still use constructor injection surely can't we? Constructor injection (in any language), to me, is a bit more explicit, ie you see it when unit test, for example. Things like `inject` (or service locators), (in my opinion only), sort of "hide" dependencies. I am sure `inject` has it's place, but not "everywhere".

Comment: I never really get the complaint about “service locators” plural. There’s only one “service locator”. Using inject is recommended by angular team

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a new Ionic/Angular project and compared the `tsconfig.json` with my own, and found it had

```
"useDefineForClassFields": false,
```

in the `compilerOptions`

I added this, and all my problems have gone away.

My mistake, the Angular upgrade actually added this, but due some "manual edit" due to merge conflicts, I removed it without knowing.

Notes on it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useDefineForClassFields)

Comment: This article gives a pretty good explanation of what's happening. Basically Typescript has diverged from the ECMAScript standard and is now moving back to it: https://angular.schule/blog/2022-11-use-define-for-class-fields